# Change background image using data binding (Kotlin)

Tags: xml, kotlin

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/gameConstraintLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:background="@{model.image}"
        tools:context=".ui.color_game.view.CakeFragment">
```

I use these codes but it does not work

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming (since we're binding a model's property to `background`) that `model.image` is not a drawable `image` is probably a `String` URL which points to an image resource online. However, even if it's neither of them, the principal to the solution is the same.

We require a way to transform our `String` URL into a Drawable and set it as background. Android has no way of knowing how to do that. Since, it does not even know if the passed values is even a URL (could be a  hex color or anything else).

Android databinding provides a way for us to do just that [`@BindingAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/binding-adapters)

All you need to do is create a static method like so:

```
class BindingAdapter {
    @JvmStatic
    @BindingAdapter("app:background")
    fun bindsUrlImageAsBackground(view: View, url: String) {
        // Use your image loading library/mechanism to load the image
        // and then bind it to view's background by calling
        // view.setBackground.
    }
}
```

A few things to notice in this method.

- The `String` `"app:background"` will be the `xml` attribute which will replace `"android:background"` in your layout file.
- The first parameter of this method must be the type of the `View` in the `layout` or its parent.
- The second parameter must be the URL you passed in the layout file and so the class/type of `model.image` must match with the second parameter.